# Engine overheating for short period of time

Tags: engine, cooling-system

I recently replaced radiator fan, thermostat and CTS (green one) and my engine is still overheating. The primary suspect is the water pump, but I could use a confirmation so I don't replace a good part.

My engine goes to 110°C but then suddenly drops back to 90°C, the engine makes a strange noise while this happens. Also the engine kind of throttles when at 110°C so I don't think the new CTS is broken. I should also say that the hose comming from the thermostat to the radiator is warm but not hot, only gets a little bit warmer when the engine makes that weird should.

Any ideas?

My car is **Audi A3 2001 1.9TDI ASV Engine**.

---

**UPDATE #1:** I just drove for about an hour on the highway and I had no overheating problems. Also when I went off the highway and drove through the city at 50km/h no overheating problems. Then I went to the gas station and turned off the car, the temperature was 90°C. Went inside bought some coffee, went back in to my car, turned ignition on without starting the car and the temperature was just above 110°C, how is this possible? I successfully replicated the problem 2 more times, just stopping, turning the car off (temperature at 90°C) and turned ignition on (temperature little above 110°C). I tried the third and fourth time but I could replicate it anymore. I will do more testing tomorrow but this is just weird. Any thoughts?

---

## Solved

I got a faulty temperature gauge, car doesn't actually overheat according to live data from OBD scanner.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have air in the system? What kind of car / engine?

Comment: @DavidLively I added my car information. I doubt there is air in the system. All VW cars apparently have a self-bleeding system, I drove the car around for about 20 minutes and it still overheated. Even tho I doubt there is air in the system is could be I don't know how to check that or bleed it manually when its not supposed to be bled manually.

Comment: Could you describe the noise or make a recording?

Comment: @Spivonious Hard to describe, I will record it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Spivonious See my updated question.

Comment: How long do you wait after turning off the car before turning it back on to check the coolant temp? All engines have a small temp spike when the cooling fan is turned off (ex. turning off the car) because residual cylinder heat works its way into the coolant system, but the radiator isn't doing much. That's normal behavior.

Comment: Solved: I got a faulty temperature gauge, car doesn't actually overheat according to live data from OBD scanner.

Comment: Also, the temp goes up when the car is shut off because coolant stops circulating, because the water pump isn’t spinning. This happens on all liquid-cooled engines. (I suppose you could have one with an electric pump that kept running for awhile after shutdown, but it’s really not an issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We seem to have lost the OP so I’m summarizing his final conclusion here:*

This turned out to be an instance of a faulty indicator, not a mechanical problem.

> got a faulty temperature gauge, car doesn't actually overheat according to live data from OBD scanner.

So by going to the source of the actual data (the on-board diagnostics), the OP was able to conclude that the problem was in the indicator, not in the car’s temperature management.

Comment: @ErikKralj glad to hear it! I didn’t mean to steal your question but it’s good to have a straight answer out there for the next person who ends up with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Remove your thermostat close it back up fill the radiator just to the top of the core . Keep the cap off  .turn your eng on . Look in side the the radiator and see if the water is moving . Have someone push on the gas pedal not to much see if the water is. Circulating.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm sure you probably didn't see, but the OP answered their own question by putting an edit into the question itself. Has nothing to do with what you're suggesting in your answer.

Answer (score -3):

if bad water pump,the radiator hoses will not feel firm and pressurized when engine fully warm. squeeze them when cold then again when hot,if not much difference in pressure its likely bad water pump.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm sure you probably didn't see, but the OP answered their own question by putting an edit into the question itself. Has nothing to do with what you're suggesting in your answer. Also, what you're suggesting doesn't stand up under the microscope. The water pump doesn't create pressure within the system, heated coolant expansion creates it.